# How can I restore Sharepoint web app when the DB is in another server?

Tags: restore

I have the following situation:
I have a Sharepoint application where the data and app are in two separated servers. I create the backup of the site using:

```
stsadm -o backup -url http://sgd -filename sgd.bak
```

In that step I'm not sure if the command automatically access the DB server and create in one file unit (sgd.bak) everything (web configurations and db data).
If the previous statement is true, then how can in another pair of servers (app and db) restore it? I try with this

```
stsadm -o restore -url http://othersgd -filename sgd.bak -overwrite
```

The "othersgd" was created using the same principles, the app is in one server and the db is in another server. Is this command capable to restore the db where corresponds?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The STSADM [backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263441%28v=office.12%29.aspx) command will back up a site collection, not a database. The content is accessed via the object model which will connect to the SQL server behind the scenes.

You can restore the backup to another site collection which will place it in the default content database associated with the Web Application that contains the restored site.

If you want to perform a DB backup you will need to jump on the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You can backup\restore a site collection using *stsadm* irrespective of the topology of the servers.

Please note that the command is not for backup\restore of web application. So you will get the data in lists\libraries in your site but not the additional configuration settings like web.config,search settings etc